# New row value to be sync with entire column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question, how to set a new row to have the same value as the column?

I have a table named `pm_sys`, it consists of a column called `mainv`

In `mainv`, I wish every row in the entire column are in the same value 
so I had `UPDATE pm_sys SET mainv=:mv` :mv is the value that inserted by user

But, when I created a new row, the mainv of the new row is not sync with the other values in mainv, the output of the new row of mainv is = 0. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
Problem Example Table:
Name    | mainv |
Susan   |   9   |
Savannah|   9   |
Trevor  |   0   | //It is not sync with the rest that already set to 9
```

Comment: You can use default constraint to keep this column always as 9 only.

Comment: Thank you, but as I've stated above, the value of ```mainv``` is can be changed but when the value is not changed, the value of the new row is not sync with the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger on your table that will update mainv column value for newly inserted record based on max value in other records mainv column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `default_mainv_value` 
AFTER INSERT ON `pm_sys` 
FOR EACH ROW  
    UPDATE `pm_sys` SET `mainv` = (select max(mainv) from `pm_sys`) WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

A [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) can be a constant expression. To change the value use `ALTER TABLE` changing the row definition.

The reason you'd want a tables returning a constant number seems very odd. If you explain it more there may be a better solution for your needs.

Comment: The sql is linked with my .php command files. As two files are affected, one is inserting new data into the interface ```addnew.php``` where as the other .php file ```setmainv.php``` is to set the mainv that will affect the mainv column to be the same.  They are two different pages but the sql command will affect the sql table that is linked with the codes

Comment: Updating the entire column with the same value is unusual. There are better patterns depending on why this is done. For large tables this is a performance problem.

Comment: I See, I will find a different way to do so, thank you very much for the help!